# What is the PDF for a log-log-normal distribution?

Tags: lognormal-distribution

A log-log-normal distribution is a continuous probability distribution of a random variable whose logarithm logarithm $\ln(\ln(x))$ is normally distributed.

What is the Probability Density Function for a log-log-normal distribution?

I could find an equation on page 27 (expression 2.3) of this [PhD thesis](https://cloudfront.escholarship.org/dist/prd/content/qt49d4d2wn/qt49d4d2wn.pdf?t=mjcstv) but I am not sure about the $\kappa$ parameter related to attenuation. Is it always there, and what is it called? Also, the variable in the example is between 0 and 1, but I wonder what the function would be for variables greater than 1.

I also found this [dissertation](https://www.worldcat.org/title/log-log-normal-distribution/oclc/27235276), but it is not available online. I wonder if there are other online materials that could be useful to study this distribution.

Comment: An exhaustive search turns up nothing in your first reference that mentions a "log-log-normal" distribution, so please tell us explicitly what you are referring to.

Comment: Expression 2.3 on page 27.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't find it--it is called an "LLN" distribution!  But since equation (2.3) gives the PDF, why are you asking what it is? The function isn't defined for $g \ge 1,$ as you can check (from the fact that $\kappa$ is negative).  Evidently $\kappa$ is a unit conversion factor to decibels.

Comment: Calling it LLN is misleading, because one could confuse it with “Law of Large Numbers”.

Comment: I have added a definition at the top of the original question.

Comment: I am asking for the “standard” definition, with a proper name for the $\kappa$ parameter. I also wonder if there is an alternative definition for variables greater than 1, as stated in the original question. I suspect that both options are possible, but I would like to double check that. This is a fairly rare distribution, with very little litterature on the subject, hence my question.

Comment: $\kappa$ is not a "parameter" in the statistical sense: it merely is a unit conversion used for engineering. It's superfluous as far as statistical or mathematical analysis might be concerned. (After all, it can be absorbed into the definition of $m_c$.)  There is no "alternative definition" because of the limited domain of the logarithm.

Comment: That makes sense, but if the attenuation unit conversion is positive or ommitted, I could totally see an alternative version defined for variables greater than 1, and I would suspect that in that case, the unusual minus sign on the numerator would go away. Would that be a fair assumption?

Comment: I don't think so: all the minus signs I see are needed.  You could define a distribution on $g\gt 1$ because $\log\log(g)$ would then be defined, but this wouldn't be an essentially different one because $\log\log(g) = \log(-\log(1/g)),$ allowing you always to assume $g\lt 1.$

Comment: I think this answers the original question. Happy to type down the LaTeX in an answer unless you want the privilege of doing it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With $\mu$ and $\sigma$ being the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal process:

$f(x) = \displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}x\ln(x)}\exp\Bigg({\frac{-\big(\ln(\ln(x)) - \mu\big)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\Bigg) \quad x \geq 1$

Comment: Now, I wonder if the “standard” definition should not just get rid of the minus sign in front of the log x term by defining x as greater or equal to 1, just for simplicity sake.

Comment: And I am still wondering about the minus sign on the numerator. If x is greater or equal to 1, don’t you want f(x) to be positive always? I have updated the answer accordingly. Please let me know if I got it wrong. It’s kinda late where I am right now...

Comment: Small typo: the "$\sigma$" in the first fraction should not be under the square root sign.